# python sqlite3 insert table error: cursor is not connected?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, insert

I try to use `sqlite3` to import data to a table `babyName` in my AWS RDS database. For the two methods I tried, the first one `data_entry()` works fine every time but the second `new_data_entry()` gave me

> Cursor is not connected

or

> Not all parameters are used

error. Could you please help me?

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

# start connection
try:
    cnn = mysql.connector.connect(
    user = '*****',
    password = '*****',
    host = '*****-mysql.*****.us-****-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    database = '*******')
    print('It works!')
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    if e.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print('Somethign is wrong with username or password')
    elif e.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print('Database does not exist')
    else:
        print(e)

# start cursor
import sqlite3
c = cnn.cursor()
def creat_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS babyName (name TEXT, gender TEXT, frequency INTEGER, year TEXT)")
def data_entry():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO babyName VALUES ('Mary', 'F', 1234, '2008')")
    cnn.commit()
    c.close()
    cnn.close()

def new_data_entry():
    name = 'Wendy'
    gender = 'F'
    frequency = 321
    year = '2006'
    c.execute("INSERT INTO babyName (name, gender, frequency, year) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (name, gender, frequency, year))
    cnn.commit()
    c.close()
    cnn.close()

# creat_table()
data_entry()
print('It works!')
new_data_entry()
```

The error message I kept getting:

```
It works!
It works!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/*****/sqlite3_python_cc.py", line 53, in <module>
    new_data_entry()
  File "/Users/*****/sqlite3_python_cc.py", line 45, in new_data_entry
    c.execute("INSERT INTO babyName (name, gender, frequency, year) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", values)
  File "/Users/*****/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 529, in execute
    raise errors.ProgrammingError("Cursor is not connected")
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Cursor is not connected
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of `data_entry` you have closed the connection to the database, `cnn`, which is saved as a variable in the global scope.  When you attempt to run `new_data_entry`, the connection has already been closed, which is what is give you the error.

Instead, leave the connection open until you are finished.

```
import sqlite3
c = cnn.cursor()

def creat_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS babyName (name TEXT, gender TEXT, frequency INTEGER, year TEXT)")
def data_entry():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO babyName VALUES ('Mary', 'F', 1234, '2008')")
    cnn.commit()

def new_data_entry():
    name = 'Wendy'
    gender = 'F'
    frequency = 321
    year = '2006'
    c.execute("INSERT INTO babyName (name, gender, frequency, year) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (name, gender, frequency, year))
    cnn.commit()

def finish():
    c.close()
    cnn.close()

data_entry()
print('It works!')
new_data_entry()
finish()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I get an error like this: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement. The problem still seems to be caused by "new_data_entry()". I connect the database using "mysql.connector" but make tables using "sqlite3"; can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem solved!

```
def new_data_entry():
    name = 'Wendy'
    gender = 'F'
    frequency = 321
    year = '2006'
    c.execute("INSERT INTO babyName (name, gender, frequency, year) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (name, gender, frequency, year))
    cnn.commit()

def finish():
    c.close()
    cnn.close()
```

Change all the "?" to "%s" and the codes all run through~ Thank you guys!